# Error: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I want to validate or upload my project to the app store I get the following:

> The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app

What do I need to change?

I just found answers for the version number, but that is not the problem.

Comment: What bundle identifier and product name are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using one of names that is used by Apple applications already, for example "Compass" or "Calculator". There is no workaround - you need to change it.

Comment: yes thats true, but it is an update. I already had the init release in january 2013. In the store the name is something like for example firmname compass.

Comment: For both: Bundle name and Bundle display name ?

Comment: yes for both is like compass. just in the itunesconnect is firmname compass.

Comment: Hmm you have to change it than to have "firmname compass" - without exact name it's hard to help :) Maybe you should contact apple support with that question - I couldn't really find a list of all IDs Apple uses.

Comment: so I should change Bundle name and Bundle display name? or anything else also?

Comment: Those 2 should be enough

Comment: but then is the name under the icon ->  "firmname compass"?

Comment: Yes - that's Bundle Display Name

Comment: and how is that working with an update? because the actual app is named: compass. is there any problem? I mean does ios understand that it is an update or are there two apps then on the screen? thanks

Comment: Updates are based on bundle identifier com.youcompany.appname - this is how iOS will identify it's the same app. User will just see updated name on dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

This now (June 2016) applies for localization as well. If you have a localized bundle display name, it can't be the same as Apple's app in that language, e.g. "Kompass" in German.